# jQuery fadeIn does not work with Z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

How come the second image fades in. I'm thinking it has something to do with `z-index`and `opacity`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('.fade-in').each(function(i) {
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object-$(this).outerHeight()/2) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity' : '1'
                }, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.fade-in {
    opacity:0 ;
}
.row {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 600px;
    background: #000000;
}
.offset {
    height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offset">scroll down</div>

<div class="row">
    <img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/main-large//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg" alt="test" class="fade-in"/>
</div>

<img src="http://assets3.parliament.uk/iv/main-large//ImageVault/Images/id_7382/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx.jpg" alt="test" class="fade-in"/>
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to re-create the **Images Lazy Load** ... just without the lazy Load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have has nothing to do with `z-index` nor `opacity`.

In your code, you're using the `.position()` method to find out the coordinates of the element to be faded-in. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/position/) describes:

> The .position() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element ***relative to the offset parent***.

If you print the first image's `.position().top()` to the console, you will see that it will be always `0`. That's because it (the first image) has a top offset of `0` relatively to it's parent `.row` element. Causing your animation to trigger automatically.

To avoid this, you should be using the [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method instead of `.position()`, because it returns the coordinates of the element relative to the `document`. This way you can have your effect to trigger at scroll with any combination of `.rows` or other layout patterns.

I hope it helps you.

**– FF**